# How to correctly configure list, map and set in Spring Java Based Configuration

Tags: java, spring

How to achieve this in Spring based configuration.

```
<util:list id="abcHandlersList">
            <ref bean="aHandler" />
            <ref bean="bHandler" />
            <ref bean="cHandler" />
    </util:list>
```

The scenario I want to achieve. I have a different paymentHandlers e.g. Paypal, CreditCard and DebitCard. In my Service I will get a list of handlers and iterate to find an appropriate handler to process my payment. I would really appreciate if you could help me with Java Based Spring configuration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen any annotations to support list , maps etc in Java Based configuration

You need to create your list and maps in your Configuration class like ,

```
@Bean
  public List<String> abcHandlersList(){
      List<String> abcHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
      abcHandlers.add(AHandler1());
      abcHandlers.add(BHandler1());
      return abcHandlers ;
 }

  @Bean
    public AHandler AHandler1(){
            return new AHandler();
    }

  @Bean
    public BHandler BHandler1(){
            return new BHandler();
    }
```

You can add the list to bean , other way around like

```
@Resource(name="abcHandlersList") 
  public void setHandlers(List<String> handlers) {
      this.handlers = handlers;
  }
```

or

```
@Resource(name="abcHandlersList")
private List<String> handlers;
```

Comment: I know how to configure using xml based configuration. I want to use Java Based Spring Configuration to achieve the xml equivalent.

Comment: Yes that worked. However one quick correction List<String> handlers should be List<Object> handlers; It should be object of type handlers.